# checking git status in Makefile

Tags: git, makefile, gnu-make

I want to know inside a Makefile if my repo is clean or not. I found that `git status --porcelain` can be my friend. I see it working within bash but I can't get it work in Makefile.

I want to set a variable in a Makefile depending on the status of `git status --porcelain`.

```
# check if return value of shell is true or false works:
$(shell true)
ifneq ($(.SHELLSTATUS),0)
    DIRTY=YES
else
    DIRTY=NO
endif   

$(shell test -z "$(git status --porcelain)" )
$(info $(.SHELLSTATUS))
```

But the last line of the Makefile always return `0` independent of the status of my repo. Maybe some missing escape sequences?

Comment: Hi. `git status --porcelain` always returns 0 (tested it myself), even if the repo is not clean. You should check length of the output instead of the return code.

Comment: @h4z3: ?? I exactly try to do so! `$(git status --porcelain)` should give a string, that is compared if zero length or not with `test -z`. And the result of this test in a shell is used with `.SHELLSTATUS`. Something is wrong, quite clear, but I can't catch the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I got confused with how you check the shellstatus. Why don't use test directly, tho? `test -z "$(git status --porcelain)"` seems to work correctly for me (0/success for empty status, non-zero/fail for stuff there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is special in Makefiles. You need to double it to propagate it to the underlying shell:

```
$(shell test -z "$$(git status --porcelain)" )
#                ~~
```

Comment: I want to use it in a Makefile. And I did not check the retval of git status ut the retval of the comparison if string is empty. So I still have no idea what I did wrong. Again: All this works in bash, that is NOT my problem. I thought instead of `|grep -q ^ ` I use `test -z`

Comment: @Klaus: Sorry, I didn't understand your question properly. See the update.